# After clean, managedObjectContext is nil and causes fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data, ios9

The error happens in two places both of which are calling the managedObjectContext. It was working fine for the past few days. Then I ran clean on it and now I am getting this error. Since it has been working this whole time I have no idea where to look. The error I get is fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value. The error happens on the let managedContext =.... I am new to core data so let me know what other code you need to see. I also included my appDelegate,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let appDelegate =
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    self.context = managedContext

    try! self.fetchResultsController.performFetch()
    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

}

    import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var context: NSManagedObjectContext!


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    //context = self.managedObjectContext


    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    self.saveContext()
}

// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "com.JohnnyCox.SalesCRM" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1]
}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("SalesCRM", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
    } catch {
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Well after searching all over the place for an answer I found the simple answer. I had renamed my coredata file and didnt change the one line in the appDelegate that asks for it. Hopefully this helps someone else from this very obvious answer.